# If you are the application owner check the logs for more information. Error 500

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I created a page in rails with a SignUp form and it works great locally, everything was fine, so I deployed the project in Heroku, where the statics_page's works perfectly, but this Form is not working and is throwing me the error:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.
>
> If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

So I reviewed the log, where everything loads fine until this comes up in red:

> 2020-01-26T02:13:09.077537+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
>   path="/signup" host=safe-shelf-03588.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=a96a3ba1-41ed-4963-8f6a-5cd3676954ff fwd="181.115.249.233"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=500 bytes=1891
>   protocol=https

I reviewed forums and the most logical reason was to review routes, but error 500 is a very common issue code for different reasons and I had no luck...

This is my routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'users/new'
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get  '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  get  '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  get  '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get  '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  resources :users
end
```

this is my database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: 'my_app_development'

test:
  <<: *default
  database: 'my_app_test'

production:
  <<: *default
  database: sample_app_production
  username: sample_app
  password: <%= ENV['SAMPLE_APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

my Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

and my puma.rb file just in case:

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/
  # deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Comment: I don't THINK it matters that you have duplicate routes. But what do you get when you `rake routes` to see the actual paths? Also just checking you don't have any migrations that haven't been run on Heroku? That's one I often forget when pushing to Heroku.

Comment: Also you can run `heroku local` and it will attempt to act like your production version locally so you can test it.

Comment: @Beartech I have access to index and static pages in Heroku, but signup link is broken, also I ran command "heroku run rake db:migrate" . I just tried to run "heroku local" and it works perfectly, everything loads with no problems at all

Comment: There should be an error somewhere in the Heroku logs, else I don't think it'd give you a 500 page.

Comment: Also can you run `heroku run rails c` and from the rails console on Heroku to try and create a new user?

Comment: @Beartech oh, this info comes up: Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
PG::ConnectionBad (could not connect to server: No such file or directory)
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Comment: OK, for future reference best to always edit your question above with new output as it can be formatted and read easier.

Comment: Have you set up a postgres DB? That's what it's looking for. And if you have you need to set your ENV variable for the password, which is under the "settings" tab in Heroku web page.

Comment: @Beartech Thank you a lot! I will take in count that suggestion. Seems like Heroku Postgree is not a free Addon service, so it doesn't matter how much I try to set up the DB, it won't work until the payment, now I know that.

Comment: Heroku has a free tier for postgres, limited to 10,000 rows. I use it for testing.

Comment: @Beartech oh I didn't notice it, the hobby-dev command was the key, I have just run "heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev", also a rake migration, and everything works fine now. You are amazing man, thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to reinstall or install the Postgree DB in Heroku with the following command:

> heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev

make a Rake db:migrate and that's it